# I Parse 1 field into 2 sepearate fields but how do I combine results into 1 record

Tags: oracle

I have data that looks like this

| COMMNUM | SALE_BASE_OPT_LIST |
| --- | --- |
| 6Y9089 | ABDAECAEHAPCAPMASKCXSP04 |

That i have parsed to be this format

| COMMNUM | OPT |
| --- | --- |
| 6Y9089 | ASK |
| 6Y9089 | P04 |
| 6Y9089 | APM |
| 6Y9089 | AEC |
| 6Y9089 | APC |
| 6Y9089 | CXS |
| 6Y9089 | AEH |
| 6Y9089 | ABD |

TO then check a Flag and separate into 2 separate fields

```sql
SELECT PO.COMMNUM,
                  CASE
                      WHEN SOP.PORT_INSTD_OPT = 'N'
                      THEN
                          LISTAGG (PO.OPT, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PO.OPT)
                  END    AS FACTORY,
                  CASE
                      WHEN SOP.PORT_INSTD_OPT = 'Y'
                      THEN
                          LISTAGG (PO.OPT, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PO.OPT)
                  END    AS MDO
             FROM PARSEOPTS PO
                  JOIN PIPELINE PL ON PL.COMMNUM = PO.COMMNUM
                  JOIN CP_DBA.SOP_SALE_OPT SOP
                      ON PO.MDL_YR = SOP.MDL_YR
                     AND PO.OPT = SOP.SALE_OPT_CDE
                     AND SOP.CNTY_SALES_PGM_CDE = 'X9A'
                     AND SOP.VEH_MAKE_CDE = 'VLK'
         GROUP BY PO.COMMNUM, SOP.PORT_INSTD_OPT
         ORDER BY PO.COMMNUM;
```

And now my data looks like this:

| COMMNUM | FACTORY | MDO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6Y9089 | P04 |  |
| 6Y9089 |  | ABD,AEC,AEH,APC,APM,ASK,CXS |

But I need it to

| COMMNUM | FACTORY | MDO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6Y9089 | P04 | ABD,AEC,AEH,APC,APM,ASK,CXS |

What is the best way to combine into 1 line as above?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to follow as the first and second half appear to be unrelated (or it is difficult to tell how they are related).

However, looking at the query and the expected output, you appear to want to not include `SOP.PORT_INSTD_OPT` in the `GROUP BY` clause and move the `CASE` expressions inside the `LISTAGG` so that you use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT PO.COMMNUM,
       LISTAGG(
         CASE
         WHEN SOP.PORT_INSTD_OPT = 'N'
         THEN PO.OPT
         END,
         ','
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PO.OPT) AS FACTORY,
       LISTAGG(
         CASE
         WHEN SOP.PORT_INSTD_OPT = 'Y'
         THEN PO.OPT
         END,
         ','
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PO.OPT) AS MDO
FROM   PARSEOPTS PO
       JOIN PIPELINE PL
       ON PL.COMMNUM = PO.COMMNUM
       JOIN CP_DBA.SOP_SALE_OPT SOP
       ON PO.MDL_YR = SOP.MDL_YR
          AND PO.OPT = SOP.SALE_OPT_CDE
          AND SOP.CNTY_SALES_PGM_CDE = 'X9A'
          AND SOP.VEH_MAKE_CDE = 'VLK'
GROUP BY PO.COMMNUM
ORDER BY PO.COMMNUM;
```